# Working on a django site and wondering would it be wise to store my media on an nfs mounted partition?

Tags: django, scalability, nfs

First, I only have experience building small-medium sized websites with php so forgive me if this question seems asinine.  I want to know if it is a common /accepted/wise practice to store media (user uploaded photos,videos,etc) in a mounted nfs share?  I was just going to put all media in a /media folder like I always have done in php, but on a huge site, having 1 million+ images in one directory would seem... not the scalable way to proceed.

Am I at least on the right track with my NFS train of thought?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are probably getting ahead of yourself. You can always migrate the media to a separate server later. I don't think NFS would necessarily be the way to go anyways. Better to just serve the media from another box directly. If you want to design this to be scalable in advance, think about using [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS), perhaps. It's easy to work with from Python, and you could even use it as a storage backend for Django.

Comment: Thanks for this advice zeekay.  I know I am getting ahead of myself, but I just want some input from people who have dealt with this issue before.  I just want to have an idea of what other people do.  We do agree that having one /media folder on app root would not be the best way to scale to millions of users, correct.  Cheers!

Comment: @Chris At some point yeah, you'll need to move the data off your app server. By the time you get to *millions of users* you'll probably need multiple dedicated media servers, and you'll need to split the user media between them. GridFS sounds like a good fit, or maybe S3/competitor.

Comment: Very eye opening stuff.  I had never heard of GridFS, but I read about it, and it sounds like something that I hope to have to use.  Thank you!  You sound knowledgeable in respect to scaling.  If I may ask, what is the largest website you have worked on, and how was the learning curve on the scaling stuff.  Cheers!

Comment: I haven't really worked on very large sites in terms of users, the largest site media-wise I've developed uses GridFS to store about 12TB worth of media.